# Javascript regex for alphabetic characters and spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex, web, filter

I need a regex for javascript that includes a-z, A-Z, and spaces

For example, the string "Bob says Hi" would be accepted, but not "There were 4 clowns"

The closest I've gotten is `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` which includes a-z and A-Z but not spaces.

Comment: The closest I've gotten is /^[a-zA-Z]+$/  it includes a-z and A-Z but not spaces

Comment: So how could it be altered to included spaces? (Also, "just spaces" or "whitespace"?)

Comment: For future reference... When asking a question like this you should provide what you have tried already in the question, as well as some examples of what you want matched and what you don't want matched by the regex.

Comment: For example, the string "Bob says Hi" would be accepted, but not "There were 4 clowns"

Comment: It looks like you have some answers that probably do what you want already. If you want to contribute, feel free to edit your original question with the info here so others will find it more useful when they have a similar question.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`/^[A-Za-z ]+$/` or `/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/`

More good stuff here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

---

or just `/\w+$/` if you also want 0-9 and underscores (\w stands for "word character", usually `[A-Za-z0-9_]`).  *But your recent edit indicates that you dont want 0-9, so use one of the first 2 above.*

Comment: `\w` doesn't match space, but matches 0-9 and underscore so your answer doesn't help.

Comment: That wasn't there in your first post. `^[A-Za-z ]+$` is what was asked for. In `^[A-Za-z\s]+$` the `\s` matches more than space (0x20). And in your example `\w+$` still doesn't match a space, but matches 0-9 and underscore.

Comment: Not working for single character not sure why?

Comment: I believe it is because the correct pattern is `/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/` notice that the lower case comes first.

Answer (score 16):

You can use this to match a sequence of a-z, A-Z and spaces:

```
/[a-zA-Z ]+/
```

If you're trying to see if a string consists entirely of a-z, A-Z and spaces, then you can use this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
```

Demo and tester here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mQhga/.

For other regex symbols, there are tons of references on the internet.  This is the one I have bookmarked and look at regularly: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml.

And, you can practice in an online tool here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html.

Comment: How can I modify this expression such that it looks for only strings that has space mandatory?

Comment: @Kush - sorry, I don't understand your question.  Do you just want to test if a string has a space in it?

Comment: From set of strings having alphabets, I need to check only strings which also has spaces in between, and ignore remaining strings. In short, looking for a compulsory space in string.

Comment: @Kush - You can use this `/^[a-zA-Z ]* [a-zA-Z ]*$/` if you allow spaces at begin/end and if you allow only spaces.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2GmbQ/ for test cases.