# How to check if string contain letter and/or whitespaces

Tags: javascript

How can I check if string contain letter and/or spaces only. What I am trying is

```
/^[a-zA-Z\\s]+&/.test(name_value)
```

But it doesn't work at all and I am not very familiar with regexes.
Correct input can be:

```
Toma Tomov
Ivan Petrov
Toma
Ivan
```

Incorrect input:

```
Toma%Tomov
$Ivan Petrov
etc.
```

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5C%5Cs%5D%2B%26%2F

Comment: You can replace your regex with something like "[a-zA-Z ]+" without quotes, if you want to check character and space string only. There is a space after 'A-Z'.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896599/javascript-code-to-check-special-characters

Comment: i believe this question is already asked many times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059370/javascript-regex-for-alphabetic-characters-and-spaces